# copy string from the local storage when click on button in Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to copy the string when I click on the button and text.select() function is not working on the string.

Can anyone tell me how can I do this

```
//getting the text from local storage
let text = window.localStorage.getItem('content');//return string

//select the text
text.select();//this give the error because this only accept the HTML collection

//range
text.setSelectionRange(0, 999999999);
//copy command
document.execCommand("copy");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [Clipboard API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Clipboard/writeText):

```
const text = window.localStorage.getItem('content');
navigator.clipboard.writeText(text).then(function() {
  /* clipboard successfully set */
}, function() {
  /* clipboard write failed */
});
```

Answer (score 0):

There's how you can copy whole localStorage as JSON string

```
async function copyJson() {
  try {
    await navigator.clipboard.writeText(
      JSON.stringify(localStorage)
    );
      console.log('Content copied to clipboard');
      /* Resolved - text copied to clipboard successfully */
  } catch (err) {
    console.error('Failed to copy: ', err);
    /* Rejected - text failed to copy to the clipboard */
  }
}
```

to make this function work on click, add `onclick="copyJson()"` to button properties in HTML